# Why is JPA creating a new entity that already exists when referred from another one during a save operation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have the following 2 entity classes managed by Spring Data (really JPA behind the scene) and for some reasons whenever I try to save a new Party into the database, it'd add a new duplicated Organizer (ie duplicate entry in table with new id).

**Organizer Class**

```
@Entity
public  class Organizer implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},targetEntity=Party.class,mappedBy="id_Organizer")
    private Collection<Party> id_Party;
}
```

**Party Class**

```
@Entity
public  class Party implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},targetEntity=Organizer.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_Organizer",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,updatable=false)
    private Organizer id_Organizer;
}
```

**Save Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createparty", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Party> createParty(@RequestBody ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> models) {
    PartyRepository = context.getBean(PartyRepository.class);
    OrganizerRepository = context.getBean(OrganizerRepository.class);
    List<Party> PartyList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map<String, Object> model : models) {
        Organizer Organizer = OrganizerRepository.findByName((String) model.get("id_Organizer"));
        // Create new Organizer if find find returns nothing
        Party.setId_Organizer(Organizer);

        PartyList.add(Party);
    }
    // Check SpringDataTemplate on how to save
    PartyRepository.save(PartyList);
    return PartyList;
}
```

Assuming for the moment all Parties can only be created by Organizers already listed in the Organizer table, the lines in the for loop in the Save method tries to find the specified Organizer and set a reference from the Party to this retrieved Organizer.

The problem is this actually saves a duplicated Organizer entry in the Organizer table using a new id.  How can we prevent this from happening if the Organizer already exists?

Not there is a cascade on the save for future cases when we want to allow someone to create a new Party using a new Organizer not yet in the Organizer table.  If this is the case, by saving the Party it should save a new Organizer as well.

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe this is happening because you have `updatable = false` in your `@JoinColumn` annotation on `private Organizer id_Organizer`. Try removing that and see if it works as expected. Also, you should verify that the `Organizer` you are retrieving is actually found and set in `Party` correctly. Also, your code would be more readable if you didn't capitalize your variable names. It is good practice to begin them with a lowercase letter

Comment: Hi thanks.  Just removed it but still doesn't work.  In fact I'm getting a circular json error with the following exception.
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Not too concerned about the json loop error as I think I can solve the json loop error by annotating the classes with the following however.

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")

Comment: Do you ever want to update Party from the Organizer? If not, I'd remove the cascading from `id_Party` in `Organizer`. You have cascading set on both ends of that relationship, so that could cause circular errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` rather than `save`. your entities are not persistent.